# Oversampled train set and test set - machine learning classification

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, oversampling

Let's say that I have oversampled my training set after splitting, then I selected the features of interest to be extracted based on the training set analysis.

After this, do I  use the oversampled training set with the testing set together to determine the classification performance (accuracy, precision, F1 measure, and etc) OR I just use the testing set for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Not really a programming question but it's important enough to be clarified imho)*

To measure performance reliably you must [use the original test set](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/104428/imbalanced-dataset-train-test-split-before-and-after-smote), without any resampling.

This is one of the reasons why the train/test split should [always be done first](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54908/data-normalization-before-or-after-train-test-split), the test set should be kept "fresh". Resampling the test set would be like cheating, because it makes the problem easier to solve.

Note: in general resampling rarely works, especially with text.